# restkit Mapping CLLocationCoordinate2D from response

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20, entity-framework-mapping

I have some geolocation data, and I need to parse it to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from object `geo`

```
"geo": [
        49.233083,
        28.46821699999998]
```

I found some information on how this could work with [`RKCLLocationValueTransformer`](https://github.com/RestKit/RKCLLocationValueTransformer), but I don't understand how to get this to work for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't go direct to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` because it's a struct, not a class.

`RKCLLocationValueTransformer` works in the same way as the value transformer for dates (which convert from `NSString` to `NSDate` instances) except that it converts from `NSDictionary` to `CLLocation`.

Your problem is that your JSON provides the location as an array, not a dictionary...

As such, you will need a different solution. You could look at making a modification to `RKCLLocationValueTransformer` (and raising a pull request). Your modification would add a different creation method (perhaps `locationValueTransformerForArrayRepresentation:`, which takes an enum parameter describing if the latitude or longitude comes first in the array). Then modify `transformValue:toValue:ofClass:error:` to check the configuration and make the appropriate mappings.

After you've done that the github page describes how to use the transformer.

Comment: Have you some example how use locationValueTransformerForArrayRepresentation?

Comment: You can't use it directly as your input JSON is wrong (change the JSON if you can). The github page has example code for usage.